# Letters ‘KINIKINIK’ are arranged such that all ‘I’s are together and the first and the last letters of each arrangement are the same. # of arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

All this boils down to is in how many ways can we arrange

Case 1: 3Ks and 4Is ( together )
Case 2: 1K, 2Ns and 4Is ( together )

Shouldn't the answer to case 1 be, [7!/(3!*4!)] for identical letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{7!}{3!4!}$ counts the number of ways to arrange three K's and four I's, but overlooks the condition that the four I's must be consecutive.

The trick you're missing is that when four Is must be consecutive, you can treat them as a single letter "IIII". So in the first case, we are rearranging three K's and one IIII, for $\frac{4!}{3!1!}$ ways.

This should empower you to solve the second case as well.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the kind help. You explained things, and my error really well. :)